# Malformed JSON: Unexpected '<' in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring

I want to produce `json` from JPA `@Entity`, I have

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Bar implements Serializable {     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    //omitting other stuff
}
```

my controller is

```
@RestController
public class BarController {

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json", produces={"application/json"})

    public List<Bar> list() {            
        return barService.findAllBars());
    }

}
```

I'm having this error in browser

[image: HTTP 406]

and in Postman 
[image: Postman Malformed JSON]

what is wrong with it.

Comment: Are you serializing your list to JSON before returning it?

Comment: I don't know how you're configuring Spring, but this often means you don't have JSON converters installed. I use Spring Boot, which does that for me.

Comment: @chrylis Spring Boot is not the choice then??

Comment: Spring Boot *is* the choice. A plain Boot setup wouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I caught up one fatal mistake which is you are getting list of Bars *barService.findAllBars()*, you may need to convert that list to json adding the method as

```
public static String toJSON(Object object) 
    { 
        if ( object == null ){
        return "{}"; 
        } 
        try { 
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
           return mapper.writeValueAsString(object); 
           } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
      return "{}"; 
      }
```

Now make change as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
    public String list() {
        return toJSON(barService.findAllBars());
    }
```

hope this works, if any issues feel free to query in comments session.

Comment: Spring has built-in support for handling that conversion in a more flexible and reliable way.

Comment: It helped, but when I have some __join__ and have a field like `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
 @JoinTable(name = "foos_bars",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foos_id"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bars_id"))
 private List<Foos> foos;` i get >org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pkj.Bar.foos, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->pkj.entity.Bar["foos"]), how to solve this one

Comment: @chrylis any example please in that case??

Comment: @chrylis if I'm `public List<Bar> list() {  
  return barService.findAllBars();
 }` I get that same issue __HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.__

Comment: @chrylis any solution or Spring magic would be great if you suggest any, in comment or in your answer please!!

Comment: @ArshadAli The 406 error means that the request `accept` header is not compatible with the `list()` method, as defined by the `@RequestMapping` attributes. Assuming you don't specify `headers=`, and you shouldn't, any `accept` value that allows `application/json` should work. Since this is likely an AJAX call, check the value sent. The browser can show you the header values. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: Can you stop harassing chrylis? Asking once is enough. You might want to take a good look at your own comments before flagging others as rude.

Comment: @ArshadAli It all started here: http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/. You're essentially suggesting reverting to using pre-2010 Spring instead of addressing the real problem.

Answer (score 5):

The "Malformed JSON" message is from the "Pretty" printing. Click "Raw" to see the actual response.

The actual response is a `406 Not Acceptable` error (says so on your screen) with a payload of HTML (hence the unexpected `<` from "Pretty") that says the request has been rejected by the server.

Remove the `headers = "Accept=application/json"` from the `@RequestMapping`. The `produces={"application/json"}` is already telling Spring to only call this method if `application/json` is an acceptable response, which it likely is, but the header might say `*.*`, or something more complex like `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`, both of which will allow `application/json`.

Of course, since this is likely an AJAX call that is expecting JSON, it *should* have listed only `application/json` in the `accept` value. Check the code executing the AJAX call if that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is something amiss with your accept header in your get request. Try setting the header to

```
"Accept=*/*"
```

and see what you get back.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonFormatter https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to test the JSON before proceeding further. Its a very good tool that validates JSON and shows you possible errors with line number.